# не активируется venv

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

Установил venv, но он не хочет активироваться. Пробовал добавить ещё окружения, но результат один и тот же.
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, удалите все папки с виртуальными окружениями в вашем проекте, чтобы ничего не напутать.
Затем в корневой директории проекта:

```
> python -m venv env
> env\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: Так и не понял в чем проблема, но если использовать `virtualenv env1` , то env1 не активируется. Но с вашим способом всё работает. Спасибо!

Comment: > python -m venv env
> env\Scripts\activate

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, находясь в папке VENV, выполнить

```
env1\Scripts\activate
```

Пользуйтесь PyCharm. Там с этим заморочек нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Оказалось, что в Windows 10 сейчас вместо activate.bat теперь работает activate.ps1
"instead of activate.bat which doesn't work in PowerShell any more."

Comment: В PyCharm можно также заменить PowerShell на cmd File-Setting-Tools-Terminall-Shell Path (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этой проблемой работая на VScode. Помогла установка PowerShell for Visual Studio Code плагина и через этот терминал с первой попытки активировалась среда!