Почему при активированном виртуальном окружении(venv) библиотеки устанавливаются в глобальное окружение, а не в виртуальное?
Я создаю(python -m venv venv) и активирую(source venv/scripts/activate) виртуальное окружение в проекте в VSC. Устанавливаю библиотеки, однако некоторые библиотеки не хотят устанавливаться в venv. Ошибок не выдает. Но по сути, работая в виртуальном окружении, проект все равно "смотрит" на библиотеки из глобального окружения и берет их. То есть, если удалить библиотеку из глобального окружения, но установить ее в виртуальное, то проект не запуститься и будет требовать библиотеку.
Также, находясь в виртуальном окружении, в интерактивной среде Python проверяю пути:
import sys 
sys.path

Возвращает:
['', 'C:\\Users\\DOrlov\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\python313.zip', 'C:\\Users\\DOrlov\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\DOrlov\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python
\\Python313\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\DOrlov\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313', 'C:\\Users\\DOrlov\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\Lib\\site-packages']


(venv)
DOrlov@i-analytic6 MINGW64 ~/Рабочая папка/Projects/admin-tools (SROS-23/Collection_of_information)
$ deactivate

DOrlov@i-analytic6 MINGW64 ~/Рабочая папка/Projects/admin-tools (SROS-23/Collection_of_information)
$ pip uninstall apscheduler
Found existing installation: APScheduler 3.11.0
Uninstalling APScheduler-3.11.0:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\dorlov\appdata\local\programs\python\python313\lib\site-packages\apscheduler-3.11.0.dist-info\*
    c:\users\dorlov\appdata\local\programs\python\python313\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\*
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled APScheduler-3.11.0

DOrlov@i-analytic6 MINGW64 ~/Рабочая папка/Projects/admin-tools (SROS-23/Collection_of_information)
$ source venv/scripts/activate
(venv)
DOrlov@i-analytic6 MINGW64 ~/Рабочая папка/Projects/admin-tools (SROS-23/Collection_of_information)
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DOrlov\Рабочая папка\Projects\admin-tools\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google_drive.scheduler import launch_scheduler
  File "C:\Users\DOrlov\Рабочая папка\Projects\admin-tools\google_drive\scheduler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'



Вывод which python при активированном и неактивированном venv:

Вывод echo $PATH при активированном venv:


А как вы, работая в Windows, активируете виртуальное окружение через source? Это же команда для Linux.

В терминале VSC использую bash(Git Bash). Активирую и с помощью venv/sctipts/activate, и с помощью source venv/scripts/activate. Работает одинаково - появляется надпись (venv).

source действительно работает, но с sys.path явно что-то не так, на моём компьютере sys.path содержит путь к venv как положено

У вас в системе точно один python установлен? Что пишет команда which python в терминале без venv и при активированном venv? что выдаёт команда echo $PATH при активированном venv? Я сейчас попробовал у себя - всё нормально работает. В powershell создал venv, в MSYS его активировал. Бинарник берёт из venv, пути к библиотекам прописывает правильно.

@PakUula при активированном и неактивированном выдает одно и то же на which python - /c/Users/DOrlov/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/python.
echo $PATH при активированном окружении укажу в теле вопроса.
У меня на домашнем ноутбуке все нормально с этим, но вот на рабочем компе проблемы.

@andreymal у меня на домашнем ноутбуке все работает нормально, а вот на рабочем компе проблемы какие-то...

@ДаниилОрлов это неверно, что при активированном venv у вас тот же транслятор. Должен быть из venv. Два пути. Откройте новый шелл и активируйте в нём. which python останется тем же, то второй путь. Удалите venv и создайте заново.

Сейчас попробовал установить расширение PowerShell для VSC и оттуда активировать окружение - получилось. Единственное, не понимаю, почему с домашнего ноутбука получается активировать окружение в терминале VSC через GitBash, а тут нет..

Помог ответ из этого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088789/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-venv
